# AngularJS: Bootstrap-colorpicker Colors are not displayed if Jquery is added above the angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, nanoscroller

I have found a strange issue where if i add Jquery above the angular js, bootstrap color picker stops displaying the colors.
In my index.html

```
<script src="assets/libs/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I am doing this so as to use custom scroller (nanoscroller) where they require Jquery to be initialized before angular. Can you please help ?

Comment: try loading [latest version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js) of jQuery

Comment: @GangadharJannu You saved the day. Thank you. Could you please add your comment as the answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue with jQuery compatibility.

Try loading the compatiable version of jQuery from [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/)

Comment: Sorry. But bootstrap requires Jquery of version less than 3.

Comment: @Indian_DEVELOPER try with 2.x version. I've updated the link